# Javascript - Modify an array duplicate without modifying the original array

Tags: javascript

I'm sure this is a stupid thing, but i can't solve it.

If i do this:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, "up"];
var duplicate = arr;
duplicate[3] = "down";
console.log(arr[3]); //"down"
console.log(duplicate[3]); //"down"
```

So why the original array got modified too? It is related to the fact that they point to the same array?

How to modify only the duplicate?

Comment: Well it looks my duplicate it's not a duplicate, but my question is a duplicate! Sorry, but sometimes it's hard to find even the way to express a question in english if you're not native english, so i didn't find similar questions even if i looked for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to clone your `duplicate` array... you can use the `slice()` method to do it:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, "up"];
var duplicate = arr.slice(0);
duplicate[3] = "down";
console.log(arr[3]); //"up"
console.log(duplicate[3]); //"down"
```

Answer (score 1):

The original array was modified because using `var duplicate = arr` just means the value of `duplicate` is now equal to the value of `arr`. Changing either one will change the value of the array.

As for copying the array and its contents, this post has a full write up [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/728360/1026459)